# SQL Query to expand single row to multiple rows for daily values

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Hopefully a simple one. I'm on Oracle 11G and struggling with a query to combine daily data and sample (event-based) data. Given two tables:

```
T1:
(
object_id int,
status varchar,
effectivedate date)

T2:
(
object_id int
daytime date, 
volume number
)

Data: 
t1
(
{1, 'Producing', 1-Jan-2011}
{1, 'Shutin', 5-Jan-2011}
)

t2
(
{1, 1-Jan-2011, 2.1}
{1, 2-Jan-2011, 241.1},
{1, 3-Jan-2011, 2.5},
{1, 4-Jan-2011, 2.1},
{1, 5-Jan-2011, 2.2},
{1, 6-Jan-2011, 2.3}
)
```

I would like a query that yields the following output:

```
object_id status     daytime     volume
1         Producing  1-Jan-2011  2.1

1         Producing  2-Jan-2011  241.1
...

1         Shutin     5-Jan-2011  2.2
1         Shutin     6-Jan-2011  2.3
```

Can someone help me out with the SQL to use here? T2 will have always a value for every day while T1 stores only status changes.

Answer (score 0):

So, do you only want `daytime` to be days where status changes are made?  In that case, a simple join would do it:

```
select object_id, status, daytime, volume
from t2 left join t1
on (t1.object_id=t2.object_id and t1.effectivedate=t2.daytime)
order by 1,3;
```

Comment: The challenge here is that I need the status to propagate forward and show a record even if there was no status change on a particular day. The correct query would yield 6 records given the sample data provided. This query yields 2 rows.

Comment: There we go.  By taking the `left join` of `t2` on `t1`, we display all of the rows of `t2`--whether or not they match the corresponding rows of `t1` via the `on` condition--and leave `null` values for the extra columns of `t1` (in this case, `status`) for rows in which there isn't a match.

Comment: Better but I need to have a non-null status for all rows in the result set. The T1.Status remains in effect from the date the entry is made in T1 until the next entry is made for the same object_id. I tried to show this in my sample output where the status shows 'producing' for Jan 2 even though there is no corresponding entry in the t1 table for this date. Given my sample data, 'Producing' should be shown for January {1,2,3,4} and 'Shutin' for January{5,6}

Comment: May I ask why you need these entries filled?  If this is merely for data formatting, then an RDBMS is not the place in which you want to do that.

Comment: Appreciate your trying to help with the query. I do need this formatted for a report, yes. Respectfully I must disagree with the statement that RDBMS is an inappropriate place for this type of thing.

Comment: An RDBMS is made for data mining and querying, not for formatting.  There are plenty of ways to format the status column in Excel.

Comment: I'm not using excel. I'm using a legacy tool with limited (non-existent) formatting capabilities. To get things back on track here, I'm looking for the solution to the originally posted question.

Comment: Export the data and either use Excel or a scripting language to loop through the rows and format things.  Again, an RDBMS isn't the tool for the job.

Comment: So the query is impossible then?